# Disable keyboard navigation in file explorer after 1.31 update

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Update 1.31 added keyboard navigation to tree widgets](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_new-tree-widget), where it will now filter items in the file explorer tree based on a search result.

Previously, when the file explorer was focused, I was able to use `A` or `shift+A` to create a new file or folder in my current directory. I am now unable to do this, as any keystrokes enter a filtering mode in the tree, rather than performing the keyboard shortcut.

The developers have added a setting to control this: `workbench.list.keyboardNavigation`, however none of the options appear to revert it to the old behaviour.

Changing this option `simple`, rather than the new default `highlight`, allows the keyboard shortcuts to work as they did previously, however the new file/folder I create are now created in what feels like an arbitrary location in the file tree, rather than the current directory which was the previous behaviour.

If anyone could shed some light on how to revert back to the previous functionality, or if I am misunderstanding how the `simple` behaviour works, that would be great.

Comment: It looks like you must have an extension that sets a context key to allow you to do what you want. See https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/pull/3432#issuecomment-461195143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this question, this has been solved as of the [1.32 update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_32#_automatic-keyboard-navigation-setting). With the tree focused, press `/` to toggle between filtering mode and operation mode.